# Broken dependencies lib32asound2

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am trying to install the lib32asound2 (`dpkg -i lib32asound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb`
) package on Ubuntu 13.1 but instead I get this message:

```
(Reading database ... 224124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace lib32asound2 1.0.25-4ubuntu4 (using lib32asound2_1.0.25-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement lib32asound2 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lib32asound2:
 lib32asound2 depends on libasound2 (= 1.0.25-4ubuntu4); however:
  Version of libasound2:amd64 on system is 1.0.27.2-1ubuntu6.

dpkg: error processing lib32asound2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lib32asound2
```

Could anyone help me out, please?

Comment: "On newer 64-bit DEB-systems with Multiarch-support (Debian 7) teamviewer_linux_x64.deb cannot be installed because the package ia32-libs is not available anymore on these systems. In this case you can use teamviewer_linux.deb instead." http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten the wrong package for use on 13.10, no need to manually install a downloaded .deb anyway

in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Basically I am trying to install Teamviewer and it keeps asking for lib32asound and ia32-libs. However, I get the following error for both:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32asound2 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs:i386' has no installation candidate

Comment: By saying I get the same error I mean that they both end up saying that "E:Package'package-name' has installation candidate"

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/234339

Comment: In the link above it is suggested that Saucy is not quite stable, yet. Could that be the case?